# Is there a configuration setting to globally set the :default_strategy to :build for all factory_girl Factories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I know you can override the default strategy for creating a Factory object like so:

```
Factory.define :person, :default_strategy => :build do
  # stuff
end

Factory.define :person, :default_strategy => :create do
  # stuff
end

# same behavior as the previous factory
Factory.define :person do
  # stuff
end
```

but I'm wondering if I can add a setting to a factory_girl config file or maybe in the `/environments/test.rb` file so that

```
Factory.define :person do
  # stuff
end
```

builds a `Person` object by default and not create one by default.

Answer (score 0):

From the [source](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb):

```
module FactoryGirl
  class Factory
    # ...
    def default_strategy #:nodoc:
      @options[:default_strategy] || :create
    end
    # ...
  end
end
```

The default strategy equals the strategy that is passed as an option to the definition, and otherwise is set to `:create`. So it seems that's it not possible to set the strategy for all factories unless you monkey-patch `FactoryGirl::Factory#default_strategy`.

Comment: I'll try this out. I guess it seems like I should submit a code patch to factory_girl.

Answer (score 0):

`FactoryGirl.use_parent_strategy`

Follow https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/pull/961 for details.